# Обнулить указатель класса обертки

Tags: c++

Как обнулить в классе обертке указатель. Кроме примера показанного в коде ниже.

```
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        char* s;
        A* p;

        B()
        {
            s = "B";
        }

        // Как в этом методе можно занулить A::p
        void Method()
        {
            p->p = nullptr;
            delete this;
        }
    };

    B* p;

    A()
    {
        p = new B();
        p->p = this;
    }
};

int main(int argv, char* argc[] )
{
    A a;
    a.p->Method();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что-то вообще непонятно, что вы хотите сделать... Но чтоб занулить `A::p`, его надо передать, потому что вообще говоря, объекты A и B никак строго не связаны. Вернее, А знает свой объект B, но B ничего об объекте  A не знает. Допустим, у вас есть `int*p = &i` - как, зная `i`, вычислить `&p`? Вот то же и здесь...

Comment: понятно, я так и думал, а как тогда можно улучшить данный способ.

Comment: Передавать при создании B "хозяина" и сохранять его.